# Separating c++ files

Tags: c++

Need a little help. I have a code that I have written out for a project. I get confused on how to separate the code into separate .h and .cpp files. Most of the searches come up with using a class. I don't have a class in this program. I am only using a map and a vector. I'm not entirely sure how to do this and I would like to know how too!

the code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


int main() {

    map<int, string> Broncos_Roster;

    Broncos_Roster[88] = " Demaryius Thomas, Georgia Tech, WR    ";
    Broncos_Roster[72] = " Garret Bolles , Utah, LT              ";
    Broncos_Roster[76] = " Max Garcia , Florida, LG              ";
    Broncos_Roster[61] = " Matt Paradis, Bosie State, C          ";
    Broncos_Roster[65] = " Ron Leary, Memphis, RG                ";
    Broncos_Roster[75] = " Menelik Watson, Florida State, RT     ";
    Broncos_Roster[85] = " Virgil Green, Nevada, TE              ";
    Broncos_Roster[10] = " Emmanuel Sanders, Southern Methodist  ";
    Broncos_Roster[22] = " C.J. Anderson, California, RB         ";
    Broncos_Roster[13] = " Trevor Siemian, North Western, QB     ";
    Broncos_Roster[32] = " Andy Janovich, Nebraska, FB           ";
    Broncos_Roster[95] = " Derek Wolfe , Cincinnati, DE          ";
    Broncos_Roster[94] = " Domata Peko Sr. , Michigan State, NT  ";
    Broncos_Roster[93] = " Jared Crick, Nebraska, DE             ";
    Broncos_Roster[58] = " Von Miller, Texas A & M, WLB          ";
    Broncos_Roster[54] = " Brandon Marshall, Nevada, ILB         ";
    Broncos_Roster[51] = " Todd Davis, Sacramento State, ILB     ";
    Broncos_Roster[21] = " Aqib Talib, Kanas, LCB                ";
    Broncos_Roster[27] = " Brendan Langley, Lamar, RCB           ";
    Broncos_Roster[31] = " Justin Simmons , Boston College, SS   ";
    Broncos_Roster[26] = " Darian Stewart , South Carolina , FS  ";
    Broncos_Roster[8] = " Brandon McManus, Temple, PK            ";
    Broncos_Roster[9] = " Riley Dixon , Syracuse, P              ";
    Broncos_Roster[42] = " Casey Kreiter , Iowa, LS              ";
    Broncos_Roster[14] = " Cody Latimer , Indiana  KR            ";
    Broncos_Roster[84] = " Isaiah Mckenzie, Georgia, PR          ";

    for (auto &it : Broncos_Roster)
        cout << it.first << " => " << it.second << '\n';


    vector<string> phoneticAlphabet;

    cout << " This is the Phonetic Alphabet"    ;

    phoneticAlphabet.emplace_back("Alpha")      ;
    phoneticAlphabet.emplace_back("Bravo")      ;
    phoneticAlphabet.emplace_back("Charlie")    ;
    phoneticAlphabet.emplace_back("Delta")      ;
    phoneticAlphabet.emplace_back("Echo")       ;
    phoneticAlphabet.emplace_back("Foxtrot")    ;
    phoneticAlphabet.emplace_back("Golf")       ;
    phoneticAlphabet.emplace_back("Hotel")      ;
    phoneticAlphabet.emplace_back("India")      ;
    phoneticAlphabet.emplace_back("Juliett")    ;
    phoneticAlphabet.emplace_back("Kilo")       ;
    phoneticAlphabet.emplace_back("Lima")       ;
    phoneticAlphabet.emplace_back("Mike")       ;
    phoneticAlphabet.emplace_back("November")   ;
    phoneticAlphabet.emplace_back("Oscar")      ;
    phoneticAlphabet.emplace_back("Papa")       ;
    phoneticAlphabet.emplace_back("Quebec")     ;
    phoneticAlphabet.emplace_back("Romeo")      ;
    phoneticAlphabet.emplace_back("Sierra")     ;
    phoneticAlphabet.emplace_back("Tango")      ;
    phoneticAlphabet.emplace_back("Uniform")    ;
    phoneticAlphabet.emplace_back("Victor")     ;
    phoneticAlphabet.emplace_back("Whiskey")    ;
    phoneticAlphabet.emplace_back("Xray")       ;
    phoneticAlphabet.emplace_back("Yankee")     ;
    phoneticAlphabet.emplace_back("Zulu")       ;

    cout << " Vector size = " << phoneticAlphabet.size() << endl;


    for (auto &itt : phoneticAlphabet)
        cout << itt << "\n";

    string query = " ";

    cout << " Please select a letter to see the ! ";
    //cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, query);

    string letters[] = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S",
                        "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};

    cout << "you entered a " << query ;

    int index = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        if (query == letters[i])
        { index = i; }

    };

    cout << " phonetic letter =  " << phoneticAlphabet[index] << endl;

    system("pause");

}
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Why not stop and ask yourself if you even need to separate it? It's not a *must thing to do*.

Comment: It is a *small* source file. Many source files have thousands of lines. Some have even more. And no, in C++ there is no reason to put every class in its own source file (I find that bad taste, but some people have different opinions). Study existing [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) projects (perhaps on http://github.com/ ...) to forge your own opinion

Comment: This _might_ be better fit on www.codereview.stackexchange.com, as your code works fine but you're looking for ways to improve it.

Comment: Instead of hard-coding everything, it's time to work on reading data in from a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, it is not really necessary to separate the code into header and source files.

But if you wanted to (say, for learning or practice), the general idea is to place function declarations in the .h file and the function implementations in the .cpp file. So, if you were to create a function, populateRoster(), you would place the one-line declaration of the function in the header file:

```
void populateRoster();
```

And then the complete function text in any source file:

```
void populateRoster()
{
    // do something...
}
```

The source file must #include the header file. Then you could call populateRoster() from main() or from any other function that includes the header file.

Of course, you could still call it from main() even without creating the header file if you just define it in the same .cpp file as main(), above main().

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really appreciate the explanation! I was doing this for learning and practicing. This was a small school assignment and just want to see how to clean it up a little bit! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to separate your code.

But, if you are obliged to, then:

Use a function to initialize your map and one for initializing your vector. Place these two functions in a source file, and provide a header file for it too.

Include that header file in `main()`, and replace the initialization code with two calls to these functions and you are done.

---

I would not separate my code in files, if I had the choice, but use the functions described above.

Comment: Thanks man! I appreciate the advice. I am still rather new and just practicing some thins to get better! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want a `class`, If `Broncos_Roster` and `phoneticAlphabet` can be public, just put them in a header file -- say `myHeader.h`; or else, put their contents into a cpp file `myHeader.cpp`, and `myHeader.h` just keep the interfaces.

Of-course, you can use OOP design concepts like:

- Use namespace: `namespace MyData { ... }`
- Use methods/functions to get the map and vector, in `myHeader.h` like:

  `const map<int, string>& get_Broncos_Roster() { // return Broncos_Roster; }`

If the map and vector in your code are constant, it's better to use C++ new feature to make them constant, like:

```
const  map<int, string> Broncos_Roster = {
     { 88, " Demaryius Thomas, Georgia Tech, WR    " },
     { 72, " Garret Bolles , Utah, LT              " },
     ... ...
     { 14, " Cody Latimer , Indiana  KR            " },
     { 84, " Isaiah Mckenzie, Georgia, PR          " },
    };

// if it's static and const 
static const vector<string> phoneticAlphabet = {
    "Alpha",
    "Bravo",
    ... ...
    "Yankee",
    "Zulu",
    };
```

By the way, to replace the map and vector to constant:

`msr -p your.cpp -t "Broncos_Roster\s*\[([^\]]+)\]\s*=\s*(.+?)\s*;" -o "{ $1, $2 }," -R`

`msr -p your.cpp -t "phoneticAlphabet.emplace_back\((.+)\);" -o "$1," -R`

See screen-shots below: ( `msr.exe` / `msr.gcc*` is a single exe tool in my open project : https://github.com/qualiu/msr in `tools` directory.)

[image: replace-to-const-map-vector]

Answer (score 0):

Considering you wrote everything in your main it is not really necessary to separate your code in source and header files. Your header file would be empty since there's no functions to prototype, and your main IS in a sourcefile.

If you have to for some reason then you would have to divide your main into separate functions first and put those in another source file with it's own header file.